# how to convert float to float64 inside a list - python

Tags: python, numpy

i have a X_train that has 16 lists  and each list has a numpy array and several other float or float64 variable. how to convert all float to float 64 inside each list?

[image: inside X_train]

[image: inside each list]

Here is my code that doesn't work unfortunately:

```
for mylists in X_train:
    for x in mylists:
        if type(x) is np.ndarray:  #this is done to skip the array inside list
            print(' numpy array')
        elif isinstance(x, float):
            float(x) #here x is a native python float variable that i'm trying to convert to float64
        else:
            print('Not even a float')
```

Comment: no, the question that you have commented is working with numpy but i'm dealing with a native python variable (float)

Comment: `np.float64()` converts to the type that you need.

Comment: 1) the `isinstance(x, float)` already tells you it's a float, so `float(x)` is a no-op. 2) even if it did convert to a float, it returns the new float. It does not convert in-place.

Comment: What's the point to making this change? If anything I'd want to change the `np.float` elements to native float.  Mixing an array and scalars (regardless of type) isn't going to be useful in most learning models.  List elements can be changed in-place, but not with that kind of iteration.

Comment: Please always provide actual example data, do **not post images**.

Comment: @hpaulj well, when i want to fit SVM i get the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". i've read many Q&A and thought that the cause of this error might be the mix of float and float64. i achieved what i want (making all elements float64) but i still get that SVM error. would you please give me your opinion?

Comment: Ok, this is a classic case of the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You weren't asking us about your *actual problem*, you were asking about your *attempted solution*, which in this case, has nothing to do with the problem you are encountering. If you read [ask] and the [help], it points out that you should give some background about *what you are trying to do and why*, to prevent this sort of thing from happening. In any case, you must provide a [mcve] about the actual problem you are encountering

Comment: Imagine an array `x=np.array([1,2,3])`.  `x[1]=[4,5,6]` would give 'sequence' error.  That's tring to assign a list (or array) to a single element slot in `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ DYZ's comment motivated me to solve this problem

```
x_train64=[]        
for (index, thing) in enumerate(X_train):
    if index < len(X_train):
        current, next_ = thing, X_train[index]
        current_list64=[np.float64(current) for current in current]
        x_train64.append(current_list64)
        if len(X_train)== index:
            print('end of X_train')
            break
```

Comment: but **why** would you want to do this?

Comment: excuse me, i don't understand your question,  would please clarify?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the `float` objects in your `list` to `np.float64` objects?

Comment: i have explained the reason in the comment section of my question (the last comment)